# How to Rank Field in ArcGIS 10.1?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, table

I have a table of crimes by precinct. There is a field with the precinct number (I.E. 1, 2, 3, 4...) I also have a field each for Burglaries, Assault, Arsons with a count of how many in each precinct. Is there a way to summarize the precinct field so that each of the three crime type fields are ranked from highest count value to lowest (I.E. 1,2,3,4... instead of the current count 45,35,43...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While sorting won't immediately give a numerical ranking, it will arrange the file so you can easily calculate it. If you need the actual numerical rank, you can add a field for each type of rank, sort on that basis, and then us `CalculateField_management` to set the rank.

[`Sort_management`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help../index.html#//001700000057000000) will allow you to sort on multiple fields, specifying ascending/descending for each.

Answer (score 1):

In ArcMap, open the attribute table.

Right click on one of the column headers and click Advanced Sorting.